Не могу разобраться во времени


let askTime = Math.floor(((1732217967809 - 1732174653061) / (1000 * 60)) % 60)
console.log((1732217967809 - 1732174653061))
console.log(askTime)



43314748
1

как вычислить разницу во времени в секундах? откуда эта единица?

В секундах — просто (1732217967809 - 1732174653061) / 1000 а вы что-то непонятное в коде нагородили


как вычислить разницу во времени в секундах?

На это ответ дали выше...

откуда эта единица?

Вот объяснение про то, откуда эта единица...


let v = (1732217967809 - 1732174653061)
console.log('Разность. В милисекундах', v)
v = (v / (1000 * 60))
console.log('Деление. В минутах', v)
let askTime = Math.floor(v % 60)
console.log('Деление по модулю. Сколько в итоге минут, отбросив часы', askTime)
v = Math.trunc(v / 60)
console.log('Деление. Сколько в часах', v)
console.log(`Итог - прошло ${v} часов и ${askTime} минут`)



